# Why is opening a file faster than reading variable content?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, zsh, variable

In a `bash` script I need various values from `/proc/` files. Until now I have dozens of lines grepping the files directly like that:

```
grep -oP '^MemFree: *\K[0-9]+' /proc/meminfo
```

In an effort to make that more efficient I saved the file content in a variable and grepped that:

```
a=$(</proc/meminfo)
echo "$a" | grep -oP '^MemFree: *\K[0-9]+'
```

Instead of opening the file multiple times this should just open it once and grep the variable content, which I assumed would be faster – but in fact it is slower:

```
bash 4.4.19 $ time for i in {1..1000};do grep ^MemFree /proc/meminfo;done >/dev/null
real    0m0.803s
user    0m0.619s
sys     0m0.232s
bash 4.4.19 $ a=$(</proc/meminfo)
bash 4.4.19 $ time for i in {1..1000};do echo "$a"|grep ^MemFree; done >/dev/null
real    0m1.182s
user    0m1.425s
sys     0m0.506s
```

The same is true for `dash` and `zsh`. I suspected the special state of `/proc/` files as a reason, but when I copy the content of `/proc/meminfo` to a regular file and use that the results are the same:

```
bash 4.4.19 $ cat </proc/meminfo >meminfo
bash 4.4.19 $ time for i in $(seq 1 1000);do grep ^MemFree meminfo; done >/dev/null
real    0m0.790s
user    0m0.608s
sys     0m0.227s
```

Using a here string to save the pipe makes it slightly faster, but still not as fast as with the files:

```
bash 4.4.19 $ time for i in $(seq 1 1000);do <<<"$a" grep ^MemFree; done >/dev/null
real    0m0.977s
user    0m0.758s
sys     0m0.268s
```

Why is opening a file faster than reading the same content from a variable?

Comment: @l0b0 This assumption is not faulty, the question shows how I came up with it and the answers explain why this is the case. Your edit now makes the answers not answering the title question any more: They don’t say whether that’s the case.

Comment: OK, clarified. Because the heading was wrong in the vast majority of cases, just not for certain memory mapped special files.

Comment: @l0b0 No, that’s what I’m asking here: “I suspected the special state of `/proc/` files as a reason, but when I copy the content of `/proc/meminfo` to a regular file and use that the results are the same:” It is *not* special to `/proc/` files, reading regular files is faster as well!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Here, it's not about *opening a file* versus *reading a variable's content* but more about forking an extra process or not.

`grep -oP '^MemFree: *\K[0-9]+' /proc/meminfo` forks a process that executes `grep` that opens `/proc/meminfo` (a virtual file, in memory, no disk I/O involved) reads it and matches the regexp.

The most expensive part in that is forking the process and loading the grep utility and its library dependencies, doing the dynamic linking, open the locale database, dozens of files that are on disk (but likely cached in memory).

The part about reading `/proc/meminfo` is insignificant in comparison, the kernel needs little time to generate the information in there and `grep` needs little time to read it.

If you run `strace -c` on that, you'll see the one `open()` and one `read()` systems calls used to read `/proc/meminfo` is peanuts compared to everything else `grep` does to start (`strace -c` doesn't count the forking).

In:

```
a=$(</proc/meminfo)
```

In most shells that support that `$(<...)` ksh operator, the shell just opens the file and read its content (and strips the trailing newline characters). `bash` is different and much less efficient in that it forks a process to do that reading and passes the data to the parent via a pipe. But here, it's done once so it doesn't matter.

In:

```
printf '%s\n' "$a" | grep '^MemFree'
```

The shell needs to spawn **two** processes, which are running concurrently but interact between each other via a pipe. That pipe creation, tearing down, and writing and reading from it has some little cost. The much greater cost is the spawning of an extra process. The scheduling of the processes has some impact as well.

You may find that using the zsh `<<<` operator makes it slightly quicker:

```
grep '^MemFree' <<< "$a"
```

In zsh and bash, that's done by writing the  content of `$a` in a temporary file, that is less expensive than spawning an extra process, but will probably not give you any gain compared to getting the data straight off `/proc/meminfo`. That's still less efficient than your approach that copies `/proc/meminfo` on disk, as the writing of the temp file is done at each iteration.

`dash` doesn't support here-strings, but its heredocs are implemented with a pipe that doesn't involve spawning an extra process. In:

```
 grep '^MemFree' << EOF
 $a
 EOF
```

The shell creates a pipe, forks a process. The child executes `grep` with its stdin as the reading end of the pipe, and the parent writes the content at the other end of the pipe.

But that pipe handling and process synchronisation is still likely to be more expensive than just getting the data straight off `/proc/meminfo`.

The content of `/proc/meminfo` is short and takes not much time to produce. If you want to save some CPU cycles, you want to remove the expensive parts: forking processes and running external commands.

Like:

```
IFS= read -rd '' meminfo < /proc/meminfo
memfree=${meminfo#*MemFree:}
memfree=${memfree%%$'\n'*}
memfree=${memfree#"${memfree%%[! ]*}"}
```

Avoid `bash` though whose pattern matching is very ineficient. With `zsh -o extendedglob`, you can shorten it to:

```
memfree=${${"$(</proc/meminfo)"##*MemFree: #}%%$'\n'*}
```

Note that `^` is special in many shells (Bourne, fish, rc, es and zsh with the extendedglob option at least), I'd recommend quoting it. Also note that `echo` can't be used to output arbitrary data (hence my use of `printf` above).

Comment: In the case with `printf` you say the shell needs to spawn two processes, but isn't `printf` a shell builtin?

Comment: @DavidConrad It is, but most shells don't try to analyze the pipeline for which parts it *could* run in the current process. It just forks itself and lets the children figure it out. In this case, the parent process forks twice; the child for the left side then sees a built-in and executes it; the child for the right side sees `grep` and execs.

Comment: @DavidConrad, the pipe is an IPC mechanism, so in any case the two sides will have to run in different processes. While in `A | B`,  there are some shells like AT&T ksh or zsh that run `B` in the current shell process if it's a builtin or compound or function command, I don't know of any that runs `A` in the current process. If anything, to do that, they would have to handle SIGPIPE in a complex way as if `A` was running in child process and without terminating the shell for the behaviour not to be too surprising when `B` exits early. It's much easier to run `B` in the parent process.

Comment: Bash supports `<<<`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, I didn't mean to imply `bash` didn't support `<<<`, just that the operator came from `zsh` like `$(<...)` came from ksh.

Answer (score 6):

In your first case you are just using grep utility and finding something from file `/proc/meminfo`, `/proc` is a virtual file system so `/proc/meminfo` file is in the memory, and it requires very little time to fetch its content.

But in the second case, you are creating a pipe, then passing the first command's output to the second command using this pipe, which is costly.

The difference is because of `/proc` (because it is in memory) and pipe, see the example below:

```
time for i in {1..1000};do grep ^MemFree /proc/meminfo;done >/dev/null

real    0m0.914s
user    0m0.032s
sys     0m0.148s


cat /proc/meminfo > file
time for i in {1..1000};do grep ^MemFree file;done >/dev/null

real    0m0.938s
user    0m0.032s
sys     0m0.152s


time for i in {1..1000};do echo "$a"|grep ^MemFree; done >/dev/null

real    0m1.016s
user    0m0.040s
sys     0m0.232s
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling an **external** command in both cases (grep).
The external call require a subshell. Forking that shell is the fundamental cause for the delay. Both cases are similar, thus: a similar delay.

If you want to read the external file only once and use it (from a variable) multiple times don't go out of the shell:

```
meminfo=$(< /dev/meminfo)    
time for i in {1..1000};do 
    [[ $meminfo =~ MemFree:\ *([0-9]*)\ *.B ]] 
    printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
```

Which takes only about 0.1 seconds instead of the full 1 second for the grep call.